# How to call WordPress functions in a custom PHP script

Tags: php, blogs, wpmu

I have a PHP script I want to use for creating a new blog in WPMU. I am having trouble calling WordPress functions like [wpmu_create_user](http://codex.wordpress.org/WPMU_Functions/wpmu_create_user) and [wpmu_create_blog](http://codex.wordpress.org/WPMU_Functions/wpmu_create_blog).

My hope is to get this script running as a [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) job from the command line and pick up new blog creation requests from an external db, create a new blog using the WordPress functions and update the database with the new blog information.

Comment: What's the code you have right now? We really need to see something in order to diagnose it.

Comment: Brian, See code below, everything between the horizontal lines is my code. I don't know how to format it so it shows all code in the special format.

Answer (score 41):

include wp-load.php file (in the root of your wordpress installation) in your php script file like so,

```
require_once("/path/to/wordpress/wp-load.php");
```

you will have to provide the abspath of the wp-load file,
now you can use all the functions of wordpress in your php script

Comment: yes it will load wordpress too... but will make all the functions avaliable for use

Comment: i tried the above solution. Works in one file but not in the consequent files.

Comment: well ofcourse it wont... if you are not including that fle in your main script(in which you included wp-load.php) it wont work... then you will have to include it in all the files.

Answer (score 33):

I've got a universal solution that **will work in any PHP file** inside the `wp-content` folder **without any adjustments** or needing to know what is mysterious `'path/to/wordpress'`

```
require_once(explode("wp-content", __FILE__)[0] . "wp-load.php");
```

It just automatically goes up to root of WordPress and loads *wp-load.php*.

You can just paste it anywhere, no matter if it's a plugin or theme file, and it will work.

I think stuff like `../../../..` looks extremely bad and when you modify the structure of your folders of a theme or plugin you can get crazy.

---

***Note***: This solution assumes you **didn't** rename your `wp-content` folder.

Comment: This does assume that you haven't renamed your wp-content folder. Great answer

Comment: Thats true, I'll add note about this to my answer.

Comment: Just add this instead:
include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-load.php';

Comment: What if your wordpress is not inside `root folder`? eg. `mywebsite.com/my/wordpress/dir`?

Comment: Helpful answer :)

Answer (score 16):

For wordpress 3.1, I had to specify the host/domain because wp-includes/ms-settings.php:100 needs it or it dies. So my script looks something like (note I am using it for a network/multiblog site):

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q

<?php 
#for multi-blog only
$blog_id = 1;

#specify host or domain (needed for wp-includes/ms-settings.php:100)
$_SERVER[ 'HTTP_HOST' ] = 'localhost';

#location of wp-load.php so we have access to database and $wpdb object
$wp_load_loc = "/path/to/wordpress/wp-load.php";

require_once($wp_load_loc);

#for multi-blog only
switch_to_blog($blog_id);

#test to make sure we can access database
echo $wpdb->prefix; 
?>
```

Comment: Thank you! switch_to_blog() was exactly what I was looking for here!

Answer (score 5):

This should work:

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-load.php');
```

i.e. When the php script is on the same server and WP is installed on the root. As most cases are.

Comment: Not in a cron job (as requested by OP) they're not.

Comment: It will fail if wordpress is not inside root of server, but in some folder like www.mysite.com/some/path/wordpress

Answer (score 2):

Following is the code I am using:

---

```
<?PHP

require_once ('/path/to/wordpress/wp-load.php');
require_once ('/path/to/wordpress/wp-blog-header.php');
require_once ('/path/to/wordpress/wp-includes/registration.php');

do_action('wpmuadminedit', '');

//Code to Connect and Select the external database

//Code to Connect to the external DB and get the new order details: 
NewBlogName=$name and AdminEmail=$email

if ( !email_exists($email) )
        {
                // email does exist, create a new user
                $name = create_name_from_email($email);
                $password = "use a default password";
                $user_id=wpmu_create_user($name, $password, $email);
                create_blog($email, $title, $user_id, $password);
        }
        else
        {
                // user exists, create new blog
                $user_id=email_exists($email);
                $password = "use existing wordpress password";
                create_blog($email, $title, $user_id, $password);
  }

function create_name_from_email ($email) {
 preg_match('/[^@]+)@/',$email,$matches);
 $name = $matches[1];
 return $name;
}

//Creates a new blog, expects user to already exist.
function create_blog($email, $title, $user_id, $password)
{
//Code to Update external DB that the order is in process

    $public = array("public" => 1);
    if (constant('VHOST') == 'yes')
    {
            $newdomain = $domain . "." . $current_site->domain;
            $path = $base;
    }
    else
    {
            $newdomain = $current_site->domain; $path = $base . $domain . '/';
    }
    $domain = strtolower($domain);
    $newdomain = strtolower($newdomain);
    $path = strtolower($path);
    $meta = apply_filters('signup_create_blog_meta', array('lang_id' => 1, $public));
    $meta = apply_filters("add_singup_meta", $meta);
    wpmu_create_blog($newdomain, $path, $title, $user_id , $meta, $current_site->id);
    do_action('wpmu_activate_blog', $blog_id, $user_id, $password, $title, $meta);


    // Update external DB  with BlogUrl, NewBlogName, AdminPassword, 

OrderStatus=Complete.

mysql_close($con);

?>
```

---

Answer (score 1):

```
require_once('../../../wp-load.php');
```

I think you have to add this line before any usage of wordpress function in your custom file. and make sure i have add ../ 3 times as per my wordpress installation structure.It's depends on your structure checks manually.
ex. if your custom file is inside your themes/yourtheme/custom.php then above code will works perfectly and if not then add ../ or remove one or more ../ as per your path.

Answer (score 1):

WordPress uses a [phpass](https://www.openwall.com/phpass/) function.

This worked for me as I had a password, and the hash in a table (migrated WordPress users) and had to find a way to check login details.

Grab this download here - https://github.com/sunnysingh/phpass-starter

All you need is this basic function to check a text password to a WordPress hash:

```
<?php
require_once("PasswordHash.php");
$hasher = new PasswordHash(8, false);

// Check that the password is correct
$check = $hasher->CheckPassword($password, $stored_hash);

if ($check) {

  // Password good

} else {

 // Password wrong

}

?>
```

All credits to Sunny Singh!