# wordpress custom page not in admin

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to create a page `test.php` that can use `wordpress` functions but is not part of the `admin/pages` section.  so basically if I have a link on my `single.php` or `page.php` to direct me to `test.php` not show the `404` but actually show me the contents of `test.php`.  I've heard that i might have to make some changes to the `htaccess` but I'm not sure how to search for this issue so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: test.php is your template file....?

Comment: it's actually a file not a template but it needs to use wordpress functions

Comment: you can achieve this by making test.php to template file...and can use wordpress functions...

Comment: ok but this will in no way be used by any pages in the admin..it's separate..it does it's own thing

Comment: Any custom plugin, `functions.php` in your theme, or file in `/wp-content/mu-plugins` will do this.

Comment: @doublesharp can u elaborate? I'm not sure I understand how.

Comment: The information for creating [page templates](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates), [plugins](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin) and using [functions.php](http://codex.wordpress.org/Functions_File_Explained) can all be found on the WordPress site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `include('../wp-load.php');` in the top of your php file to get wordpress functionality in to your file then place your file in the root wordpress installation and then you can call your file with your url http://yourdomain.net/test.php

The information for creating page templates, plugins and using functions.php can all be found on the WordPress site.

[How to call wordpress functions in custom php script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091521/how-to-call-wordpress-functions-in-custom-php-script)

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( is_admin() ) {
    add_action( 'admin_menu', array( 'adminAddPage' ) );
}

/**
 * Callback to add page
 */
public function adminAddPage() {
    add_options_page( 'Custom page title', 'Custom page title', 'manage_options', 'custom_page_slug', array('adminPage') );
}

/**
 * Page HTML Callback
 */
public function adminPage() {
    // your html code
}
```