# Is it true that we can't call wp-load.php in our plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

in my plugin I wrote

```
 require_once('../../../wp-load.php');
```

but the administration said me that I can't call this file.. How can I load functions from this file whitout calling ??

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091521/how-to-call-wordpress-functions-in-custom-php-script

Comment: Have you tried to find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You may instead require_once the wp-blog-header.php file.

http://codex.wordpress.org/User:Jalenack/Integrating_Wordpress_into_an_Existing_Site